# How to visually resolve conflicts from rebase in SourceTree

Tags: git, rebase, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree for Windows and attempting to *rebase* entirely with SourceTree. I would like to perform a visual resolution of the files.  I do not understand how to setup the configuration so that `git -rebase` will popup diffmerge window with `Launch external merge tool` command from SourceTree
Is this possible? What would be the config if it is possible?

My *.gitconfig* file looks like this

```
[merge]
        tool = diffmerge
[diff]
        tool = diffmerge
[difftool "diffmerge"]
        cmd = diffmerge \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = 'C:/DiffMerge_4_2_0_697_stable_x64/sgdm.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = 'C:/DiffMerge_4_2_0_697_stable_x64/sgdm.exe' -merge -result=\"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\"
    trustExitCode = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you possibly mean SourceGear instead of Sourcetree?  The paths you are listing point to the SourceGear DiffMerge.

Git on Windows needs the configuration to match what is posted on this page in order to launch diffmerge:  http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/webhelp/sec__git__windows__github.html.

After that you can either just call DiffMerge if all your files are on your disk, or you can use git diff and then specify the tool in the options.  Check out this post here on SourceGear's forum:  https://support.sourcegear.com/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=22329&p=77867#p77867.

Comment: No, I am using SourceTree. I'll write up the solution that worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are expecting to be presented with a way to resolve the conflicts but are not seeing that?

- If so, maybe you are experiencing behaviour attributable to this open [SourceTree bug](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-2493).

  (During an interactive rebase, appears to "stop", "hang", "halt" upon encountering a merge conflict.)

**Here is a Solution:**

1. **Do not** click the `Close` button on the message dialog box.
   **Close SourceTree** by right-clicking on the taskbar button and clicking close.
2. Re-open SourceTree, resolve the conflicts and commit.  (The commit message will have to be entered manually - another bug.)
3. Click `Actions` > `Continue Rebase`.

(Repeat steps 1 to 3 above for additional conflicts)

Comment: thanks for taking a look at this. I can't verify as I am no longer working with SourceTree. At the time, SourceTree only worked with Bitbucket and GitHub as Atlassian is the owner of this free tool.